How much tallow will I get?
I’m wanting to make my own beef tallow, lamb fat or chicken fat.
Want the process to be as easy and productive as possible.
I would imagine certain cuts of fat are better to make tallow from.
Can you advise which parts I should search for and how much tallow I can expect to get from it?  Eg 1kg of fat is likely to give you 200g of tallow.
I’ve seen some fat cubes online they’re just small diced cubes of fat.  If I get say 1kg of them how much tallow might get rendered from them?
I’m also considering lamb and chicken but with chicken I’m not sure if the process is easier you might need to gather a lot for of chicken skin to make an equivalent amount of fat and it will be more messy compared to using cuts of beef perhaps.
So just want to know what the easiest approach to but yielding the most tallow/animal fat.
Thanks
